# How to get SNS published message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an application that publishes messages via Amazon SNS to specified target. I need to get this message somehow using python. What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 11):

Amazon SNS does not directly allow messages to be retrieved.  Rather, for a given *topic* in Amazon SNS, you configure subscribers.  Subscribers can be, for example, an email address, an Amazon SQS queue, an HTTP endpoint or a few other options. See https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/ (search for "How does Amazon SNS work") for an overview of how it works.

### Using an SQS Queue

To receive a published from a python script, your best bet is to setup a new Amazon SQS queue for your script, and to subscribe the Queue to the SNS topic.

You can then poll the SQS queue to see if there are any messages in the queue.

This technique has the extra advantage that you won't miss any messages even if your python script is not running - they will be waiting there for you in the SQS queue.

[boto](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/) is a great python library for interracting with Amazon, and [this tutorial](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/sqs_tut.html) explains how to access an SQS queue.

### Using an HTTP Endpoint

Alternatively, if you can deploy your Python script as a web application with an Http endpoint as an API, you can subscribe your Http endpoint to the SNS topic, and your endpoint will get invoked each time there is a new message.  This techique is not recommended as if your script is offline, you will miss messages.

Comment: So, my app publish message not to some topic, but to some TargetArn. But subscribe method requires topicArn param: what I should send as TopicArn and how I can create sqs subscriptions for such messages?

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood the question.  Will update by answer, but just to confirm - a few questions about the app that is publishing the messages - 1) what is the reason to publish to a target and not a topic?  2) Can you change that app?

Comment: I can not change the app, so I need to catch messages that are published to some targetArn.

Comment: What is the targetArn used by the app?